# Bootstrap won't detect jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML document has Bootstrap, but Bootstrap won't detect jQuery. Here is my `<head>` tag:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

But it gives to me this error:

`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap JavaScriopt requires jQuery`

Comment: You don't have to use more than one jquery version in the same document. what's the version of your bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these 3 script tags, preferably 2nd one.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
    **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>**
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

Using jQuery.noConflict, you can make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page.  For instance

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
<script>
   var jq1 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   var jq2= jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   var jq3 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

but as mention above use only one version of jquery.